# Media Queries Not Showing Up On Heroku App

Tags: html, css, heroku, media-queries

This is my first time in ten months asking for help like this because so far I have always been able to source the answer or figure it out. Thank you for your time and help.

I have spent countless hours building this website for my kid sister who is starting a business and I have everything done. Locally it is perfect but on Heroku only the desktop version works and none of the media queries are kicking in. I am NOT using a framework - just JavaScript, HTML, CSS, NodeJS/Express. I have hosted on heroku before as well this same app but that time, because I am still a noob, I had styled two of my pages as 67% zoom. I could not figure a way to make the PUG pages render that way so I had to redo the styling for those pages.

So before, only the mobile versions worked and not the desktop. Now, only the desktop version works and not the mobile... I have combed through my code, css and node, and tried various fixes from adjusting the route I serve static files from to inserting periods and backslashes in front of the style links.

Here is the link to the github: https://github.com/MagentaSpruce/nettlesHerbs

I have checked all the google answers I could find - I have over 6000 lines of CSS in two separate files so using code here in the views would be a terrible and last last-ditch option

Again, EVERYTHING WORKS locally and I think it is just a heroku issue but I need help at this point. It is a large project and this is my first time posting on here

Here is an example of a media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px) {.nav-link {font-size: 6rem;}
```

Here is how I am importing the style sheet into the .html files:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" />
```

and here is how I am importing the style sheet into the PUG files:

```
        link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style2.css')
```

I have this same meta tag in the head of ALL relevant files, both .index and .pug:

```
       meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
```

My file tree has the public folder: public -> css -> STYLESHEETS HERE

this is how I am serving static files: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

I have already tried using /public

I have tried ../public/css/style2.css       I have tried ./css/style2.css    I have tried /css/style2.css   I have tried /public/css/style2.css          Any time I use public none of the styling works in heroku at all. If I do either ./css or /css than the desktop styling shows up fine and when I go into google dev it shows media queries there but when I visit the site on heroku or from my dev site using a mobile the site is terrible - desktop version squeezed into mobile with 0 responsiveness.

Please let me know what else I need to provide here. I do not mean to give offense but my sister is depending on me to get this working for her business and I am willing to pay for a working solution. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

For those poor souls struggling as I was in pity and despair, FEAR NOT! I figured it out!!!

Now - if you are using a framework, well, IDK - maybe this works, maybe it doesn't.

HOWEVER! If you are using nilla, then check your media queries. Heroku build process will make screwy more advanced media queries like this one causing them not to show up! - even though everything works perfectly in google dev! Rascal!

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {}
```

So if you are trying to do stuff like this, well - won't work on Heroku. Instead, just simplify it like so,

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
```

and voila, your media queries will now be working on your heroku deployment. Weeee!

Thanks friends!